# Add active state to wordpress admin-bar element

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a custom wordpress admin bar for a specific user group. Does anyone know a way to add a active state to a wordpress admin bar element, so that I can highlight it if the user is on that specific page I'm linking to? I couldn't find one..

Here is a sample code how I created the custom menu:

```
$wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array( 
        'id' => 'benutzerprofil_link',
        'title' => __( 'Ihr Benutzer Profil' ), 
        'href' => get_page_link(507) ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your theme is using the function [**`body_class`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class):

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

It's simply a matter of adding the following rule to your `style.css` theme file:

```
body.page-id-507 #wp-admin-bar-benutzerprofil_link { background: #c00; }
```

Another solution:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'style_so_15437172' );
function style_so_15437172() 
{
    if( is_page(507) )
    {
        echo '<style>#wp-admin-bar-benutzerprofil_link { background: #c00 !important;}</style>';
    }
}
```